# Logged into Stackoverflow using scrapy and pyquery but could not do further scraping

Tags: python, scrapy, stackexchange

I am currently learning web scraping using scrapy and trying/learning various methods to login into stackoverflow and then extract some questions for practice web scraping. I have successfully logged into stackoverflow using scrapy and pyquery using following code:

```
import scrapy
import requests
import getpass
from pyquery import PyQuery
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/users/login']
    
    # def login_page(self):
    # Fetch the fkey
    login_page = requests.get(start_urls[0]).text
    pq = PyQuery(login_page)
    fkey = pq('input[name="fkey"]').val()

    # Prompt for email and password
    email = input("Email: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()

    # Login
    response = requests.post(
        start_urls[0],
        data = {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'fkey': fkey
        })
    print(response)

    def parse(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        
    def get_questions_link(self):
        pass
```

But in response, it is only giving me success status code i.e. 200 using following command to run:

```
scrapy crawl stackoverflow -L WARN
Email: test@gmail.com
Password: 
<Response [200]>
```

So, how can I get the response of whole html page data, so that I could scrape some more questions/data. The parse function is also working but it is only opening stackoverflow login page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the Requests library for the final POST request that you're making.  The response that comes back from `requests.post()` will make the body of the response available in a number of ways.  See: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content.  You should check the response code for a 2XX value via `response.status_code`.  A shortcut for that is to just check `response.ok`.  Once you do that, you can get the response body as text:

```
response.text
```

which is what you'll want if you're expecting a web page (HTML) to come back.

If you get back JSON, you can get the resulting data structure expanded from that JSON, via:

```
response.json
```

If you're not sure what to expect will come back, check the `Content-Type` header value.